# Is there a way to make bubbles float using Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to get bubbles to float from side to side as they fall, but haven't been able to come up with any solution. I could just use keyframes to move them side to side, but that would move the whole cluster. Is there any way to have each bubble move individually? Is using Geometry Nodes actually the way to go, or should I be using something else like particle effects?[image: basic "bubble" geometry node set up so far]

Answer (score 6):

Once you animate your bubblez on Z axis (and to spawn them it's probably better to use multiple planes and Poisson disc so they don't overlap), it's probably best if you use *Noise Texture* which you can tweak to control the granularity of offsets to simulate water currents. You can animate the noise to simulate the gradual change in those currents. For browning motion you could add roughness to the noise. If you don't like the Z offsets which makes the bubble periodically, randomly, significantly accelerate or slow down, you may increase the vector divisor for just Z axis. Or you can replace *Vector Math > Divide* with *Multiply* and just multiply the Z offset by 0. The *Vector Math > Subtract* {0.5; 0.5; 0.5} is there just to not make the bubbles biased towards +x and +y (color component range is from 0 to 1).

[image]

[image]

Comment: niiiiiiiiiceeee