# complex geometry bending in wind while maintaining length and individual dimensions (geometry nodes)

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, physics, scene, effects

I'm working on a scene which includes a grass field that is affected by a strong wind.
Therefore the desired result is a bending affect in the grass, due to the wind force.
For the grass I'm using a grass clump from an asset library.

I have seen posts in the forum that tried something similar with a simple bezier curve as the geometry which is supposed to be affected by the wind. Unfortuantely I failed to apply there solution to a more complexe geometry. Therefore I'm asking here in a new post for help.

In the following, there is my current geo node setup and the results it is generating. The two main problems for me are the distortion (increased width) that is happening on some of the leaves and the stretching of the length of the leaves.

[image: grass with increased lengths and distortion of leaves]

[image: node setup]

[image: increased values for visualizing distortion]

[image]

Comment: can you share the file to play with?

Comment: I added the blend.file to the question. thank u for the interest

Comment: See this: [Grass wind bending with simulation nodes and maintaining length](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/300195/60486) and then convert the curves to mesh, using either a "Curve Line" profile for flat blades, or something else like a "curve circle" for circular blades (or just 3 vertices of the 'circle' for a triangular profile, you can pass it through a transform to flatten it on one side a little bit etc.) - I don't think it's a reasonable approach to deform the entire mesh.

Comment: Yes, it‘s the post I‘m referring to in my text. And I know it‘s possible to expand the approach shown there to make it more grass-like. Me, I‘m interested in finding a method I can apply on a number of different nature assets (more complex plants, trees). So it‘s possible to create a wind effect for complex nature scenes, without having to create all of it inside geometry nodes.

Comment: Has anyone any other leads on how to solve the problem? Would be super thankful!!

Comment: It seems you want to (basically) reproduce the cloth simulation in geometry nodes. Can be done, and the system used in Blender is open sourced, you can read the implementation - you probably would be satisfied with some simplifications, but thinking about it, I think it would still turn out to be too complex for me to bother to write it into an answer: grass alone will need to interact with gravity, have its stiffness, that's an interaction based on edges, you also probably want to maintain volume… This could easily turn out to be the most complex answer I've ever written…